# Activating a USB / Bluetooth dongle ASUS USB-BT500

Tags: usb, bluetooth, asus, dongle

The instructions from ASUS suggest the following instruction, but it is not working for me I am following the instructions for 64-bit Linus, but I can't get it to work.

```
$ sudo make install INTERFACE=all
[sudo] password for rogier: 
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

The instructions say this:

```
===============
  REQUIREMENT
===============

The supported kernel version is 2.6.32 - 5.7.1

=============================
  QUICKLY INSTALL AUTOMATICALLY
=============================

  $ sudo make install INTERFACE=all
or
  $ sudo make install INTERFACE=usb
or
  $ sudo make install INTERFACE=uart
```

There's a whole lot more, but it does not seem pertinent.

Comment: Linux rogier-HP-Z4-G5-Workstation 5.15.0-78-generic #85~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 17 09:42:39 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux